# Transform a string to an object pointer?

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a string `'MyButton'`.

How can I get the OBJECT `MyButton` from the STRING `'MyButton'`, so that I could write:

```
MyButton.Caption := 'My new Caption';
```

This would change the caption of the `TButton` **MyButton** object instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the component has an `Owner` assigned (as all components placed at design-time do), then you can use the Owner's `FindComponent()` method, eg:

```pascal
procedure TMyForm.DoSomething;
var
  Cmp: TComponent;
begin
  Cmp := Self.FindComponent('MyButton');
  if Cmp <> nil then
    (Cmp as TButton).Caption := 'My new Caption';
end;
```

Comment: @user1580348: Compared to what? If you do this with GUI controls, in response to a user action, it is fine: you probably don't have millions of controls on your form, and the user is unlikely to click a million buttons per second. Still, referring to controls (and, more generally, components) by their names isn't the fastest way of doing things. Typically, one finds a different solution. But of course we don't know what your scenario is.

Comment: If you want it to be quick, don't throw away the reference in the first place!

Comment: If my string contains `'MyButton.Font.Size'`, how can I get the VALUE of the property `MyButton.Font.Size`?

Comment: @user1580348 for that, you will have to break up the string and use the substrings to [drill into the object's RTTI](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Working_with_RTTI) at runtime. Find the `MyButton` object, then use its RTTI to find its `Font` property and read that value to get its object, then use that object's RTTI to find its `Size` property and read its value.